# How to remove factors from a graph using plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to use plotly on an existing ggplot2 graph to allow me to interactively filter out results from a particular group. However I can't get the axis to update to remove the levels which are no longer needed.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

data(iris)

mtcars$car_name <- row.names(mtcars)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = car_name, y = disp, color = as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()+
  coord_flip() 

ggplotly(p)
```

This produces a graph with the cylinder levels as factors and when I click on a level it removes the corresponding points from the graphs (which is what I wanted), but it doesn't remove the cars which no longer contain any data. For example, if I click on "8" it removes everything with 8 cylinders, but Merc 450SE is still listed on the y axis.

Essentially I'd like the graph to "refresh" and remove all the unused levels from the axis - is there an easy way to achieve that?